# Moodle get course information + all lessons through Api

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I am trying to collect all information related to Moodle course (course + lessons) Using Moodle Api I got the course information, but gets only some basic information, I want course details and its lessons (created under course)

```
    Eg :  var domainname = 'http://<server URL>/moodle'; 
var token = 'df337369637c692303d903f8cacf1eb0'; 
var functionname = 'core_course_get_courses'; 
var serverurl = domainname + '/webservice/rest/server.php' ; 
var data = {
            wstoken: token,
            wsfunction: functionname,
            moodlewsrestformat: 'json'              
                } var response = $.ajax(
               {   type: 'GET',
                   data: data,
                   url: serverurl
               }
              );
```

And the output looks like

```
{"id":2,"shortname":"IV Support Queries","categoryid":1,"categorysortorder":10001,"fullname":"IV Support Queries","displayname":"IV Support Queries","idnumber":"","summary":"<p>IV Support Queries Desc<br \/><\/p>","summaryformat":1,"format":"topics","showgrades":1,"newsitems":5,"startdate":1479168000,"numsections":5,"maxbytes":0,"showreports":0,"visible":1,"hiddensections":1,"groupmode":0,"groupmodeforce":0,"defaultgroupingid":0,"timecreated":1479127227,"timemodified":1479198758,"enablecompletion":0,"completionnotify":0,"lang":"","forcetheme":"","courseformatoptions":[{"name":"numsections","value":5},{"name":"hiddensections","value":1},{"name":"coursedisplay","value":1}]}
```

I want the lesson details created under course .How can i get the information through Api . Thanks

Comment: 1 - What version of Moodle are you using?

Comment: Moreover: what details are you talking about? Activities (i.e. modules)? Sections? Be precise.

Comment: Using latest version moodle-3.1.3.Firstly create one courses and lessons for each courses ,Want to retrieve the course + lessons .

Comment: Finally got the solution using "core_course_get_contents" and "core_course_get_courses".

Comment: OK. You could write the answer yourself, for future reference.

Comment: Yes sure @Aldo Paradiso

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using function

> "core_course_get_contents"

getting all the informations related with course.

```
var domainname = 'http://<server URL>/moodle'; 
var token = 'df337369637c692303d903f8cacf1eb0'; 
var functionname = 'core_course_get_contents'; 
var serverurl = domainname + '/webservice/rest/server.php' ; 
var data = {
            wstoken: token,
            wsfunction: functionname,
            moodlewsrestformat: 'json' ,
            courseid: 2 //Retrieve results based on course Id 2            
           } 
var response = $.ajax(
               {   type: 'GET',
                   data: data,
                   url: serverurl
               }
              );
```

Thanks